# why string concatenation getting strange result in c++?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two strings in C++:

```
"G1-2" + "-%02d.jpg"
```

and I am getting the following result:

```
G1-2-1537817269.jpg
```

Why isn't the result like this: `"G1-2-%02d.jpg"`

Comment: Can you show some code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Needs example code because it'll be hard to reproduce.

Comment: inb4 (a)s(n)printf, boost format, fastformat etc.

Comment: Are you concatenating string literals?

Comment: @onder: Come on ... how can we tell without code? Please paste your code, and we will help,

Comment: for someone who should know the answer this is a fairly easy question?

Comment: @jrok, You can't add two pointers (decayed from the literals), so I'm guessing not.

Comment: @onder, We have no idea what you're doing wrong because we mainly have no idea what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @chris Don't say "can't" until you see their code...

Comment: That code won't compile (http://ideone.com/9dhULq).  Please post some real code so that we can answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

Wild guess!

You're printing the concatenated string by

```
printf(str);
```

where `str` is `"G1-2-%02d.jpg"`

```
printf("G1-2-%02d.jpg");
             ^^^^
//            but, where is corresponding integer in the following?
```

As you can see there's a `%02d`  in the string and `printf` will seek for a integer argument. It can not find it and undefined behavior occurs. In the best situation it prints out a random value with the string.

If my guess is true, then try to print the string in this form:

```
printf("%s",str);
```

or use double `%` as Chis mentined:

```
"G1-2-%%02d.jpg"
```

Comment: Not a bad guess, actually. And of course `%%02d` would fix it.

Comment: [called it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411622/why-string-concatenation-getting-strange-result-in-c#comment27045842_18411622)

Comment: This fixes the general problem of format string: `printf("%s", "G1-2-%02d.jpg");`

Comment: %%02d it works thanks chris

Comment: I hope you're gonna fix the cause, not just the symptom. Or use `puts` instead.